# ¿Alguien sabe porque sucede este error en reportlab?

Tags: pdf, reportlab

Este es mi programa, creo la ruta, creo el archivo, pero al momento de crear el pdf me dice Bad file descriptor que es el que esta por default en el programa de reportlab que es 'wb'
[image: Codigo fuente]
[image: Este es el error que me produce]

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import os

def crear_pdf(nombre_archivo):
    # Crear un lienzo para el PDF con tamaño carta (letter)
    c = canvas.Canvas(nombre_archivo, pagesize=letter)

    # Agregar contenido al PDF
    c.drawString(100, 750, "¡Hola, este es mi PDF creado desde 
Python!")
    c.drawString(100, 700, "Aquí puedes agregar más contenido.")

    # Guardar y cerrar el lienzo
    c.save()

# Nombre del archivo que quieres crear
nombre_archivo_pdf = "mi_archivo.pdf"

ruta_completa_carpeta =
```

r"C:\Users\USUARIO\OneDrive\Documentos\Python json"

```
# Combinar la ruta de la carpeta con el nombre del archivo
ruta_completa_pdf = os.path.join(ruta_completa_carpeta, 
nombre_archivo_pdf)
# Crear la carpeta si no existe
if not os.path.exists(ruta_completa_carpeta):
    os.makedirs(ruta_completa_carpeta)

# Ruta completa del archivo PDF
ruta_completa_pdf = os.path.join(ruta_completa_carpeta, 
nombre_archivo_pdf)


# Llamar a la función para crear el PDF
crear_pdf(nombre_archivo_pdf)
```

Comment: Si existe el archivo en la ruta:
C:\Users\USUARIO\OneDrive\Documentos\Python json\file.pdf ??

Comment: Puse este codigo

Comment: Edite la pregunta, si alguien me puede ayudar porfavoooor

Comment: puedes pegar tu código, es dificil replicarlo si es una imagen

Comment: ya viejo, de verdad muchas gracias, por seguir al tanto jajaja tkm

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código el error que encontré fue que tienes que generar el archivo en la ruta final:

cambiando

```
# Llamar a la función para crear el PDF
crear_pdf(nombre_archivo_pdf)
```

por:

```
# Llamar a la función para crear el PDF
crear_pdf(ruta_completa_pdf)
```

también trata de abrir el visual studio como administrador

Comment: muchas grcias viejo, lo intento y te aviso tkm

Comment: sigue sin poder hacerlo, cree el archivo aparte, pero aun asi, dice que no lo puede crear

Comment: Aparece este error:

Comment: File "c:\Users\USUARIO\OneDrive\Documentos\Python json\aaaa.py", line 32, in <module>
    crear_pdf(ruta_completa_pdf)
  File "c:\Users\USUARIO\OneDrive\Documentos\Python json\aaaa.py", line 14, in crear_pdf
    c.save()
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1286, in save
    self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 217, in SaveToFile
    f.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: igual intente correr visual estudio como administrador pero tampoco

Comment: Trata de crear un virtual enviroment para tu código, creo que por ahí va el error, ya probé en varias maquinas y si funciona. revisa este [enlace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) de referencia

Comment: Va de verdadmuchas gracias, espero q sea eso, te loagradezco

Comment: (pdfro) C:\Users\USUARIO\Envs\pdfro>python pddfro.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Envs\pdfro\pddfro.py", line 32, in <module>
    crear_pdf(ruta_completa_pdf)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Envs\pdfro\pddfro.py", line 14, in crear_pdf
    c.save()
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Envs\pdfro\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py", line 1286, in save
    self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Envs\pdfro\Lib\site-packages\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py", line 217, in SaveToFile
    f.close()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: no se que onda la verdad, lo corri en un entorno virtual, tal vez es la version de pdf o algo, pero ps no me crea el archivo, de verdad gracias por estar al tanto